# Declaring a List before an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

In this statement `List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Why declare Mylist as a List of type String. just to make MyList a new instance of an ArrayList type String?

It seems unnecessary.

Comment: In that way, if tomorrow your boss says, "I don't want ArrayList in my code cause reminds me my ex-wife put `LinkedList` instead". So then you ensure that you only have to change 1 line.. that is object creation `new LinkedList<>()`, You follow a contract rather than an implementation, you forget about implementation details.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis and PakkuDon, good boys have a cookie...

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase Item 52 of Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, using the interface instead of the class makes the surrounding code much more flexible. So if you wanted to change `myList` to something like a Vector, you wouldn't have to change the surrounding code much if at all. Bloch goes on to say that there are certain times, such as major updates to java, when other types of Lists are updated for effectiveness or new ones are added entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `MyList` as type `List<String>` guarantees that you won't use methods only available for `ArrayList<String>`.  That way, you can change the right-hand side of the declaration in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is just an Interface, not an implementation. There are many different types of lists, such as `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

So if you declare `MyList` an `List<String>` it could possibly be any type of `List`, as @espertus said, you can change what type of list `MyList` is in the future without having to change it's declaration.